# Triton easi fit t80 electric shower - UK

Tags: electrical, shower

Just had a small extension built to the side of the house and an electric shower which runs from the mains water fitted.  On first powering the unit, with the economy (lowest heat setting) selected, as soon as the powered double pole switch is turned on, you can hear the water in the can beginning to heat.  this happens BEFORE  the shower is operated by the on/off button on the actual shower unit - i.e. power is getting to the elements BEFORE water is flowing.
As a result, the TCO burned out after  a few turn-ons.  I replaced the TCO and the unit is working again, but doing the same thing.  We have to make sure the selector on the shower unit is set to COLD setting before switching on the mains, and then adjust the temperature after the unit has been switched on, giving water flow.  Normally, with every other shower Ive had, it is perfectly acceptable to leave the temperature settings where you last had them so that you can just turn on the shower next time.
So, why would the unit be heating up water as soon as it gets power, but before water is flowing?  The water pressure is fine.
Any suggestions would be most appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I imagine it is because of the way it is designed.  It is common of North American hot water tanks to work this way.  You need to insure the tank is full before turning on the power, every time you drain the tank(not often).  You should contact the makers of the shower heater, there might be a defect, or you need another type if it bugs you to much.

Comment: What does the manual say about how this is supposed to work? Is it supposed to preheat? Is it under warranty? Is there a customer service number?

Comment: Its either faulty or installed incorrectly, pictures might help

Comment: its not installed incorrectly -theres only a water connection ad an electrical connection to the mains, both which were done by qualified tradesmen.  Also, it is not supposed to pre-heat any water in the small can - this should only be heated once the unit is switched on.  Brand new unit, water inlet and earth live and neutral connected from double pole switch, nothing else to do.  It is under warranty, but have been told the call out charge from Triton will be £85.00 !!!  the unit only cost £100.  Just thought someone might have some idea as to what's causing it?

Comment: qualified tradesmen make mistakes too...

Comment: Alan Birtles - Thanks for your input but honestly, there is nothing wrong with the installation.  Its a new unit, and the only connections to be made to it are a water connection and an electrical connection - 3 wires into a terminal block.  Nothing else.  it is part of a new extension and all the electrical wiring and install has been checked and passed for a safety certificate required by the local council.